# d3.csv getting column in the wrong array

Tags: csv, d3.js

[image]I have a csv file with 2 columns, `Number` and `Value`. I am using the below code to get `Number` column in `field1` array and `Value` column in `field2` array. However when I run the code, `field1` stays empty and `field2` gets the `Number` column.

```
var field1 = [];
var field2 = [];

d3.csv("data.csv", function(csv) {
    csv.map(function(d) {
        field1.push(+d.Number);
        field2.push(+d.Value);
        debugger;
    })
});


//data.csv file is :
Number,Value
1,1000
2,1100
3,2000
4,1900
```

Comment: Please share your CSV (just the header and a couple of rows), **exactly** the way it is. Besides that, you want a `forEach` here, not `map`.

Comment: Number,Value
1,1000
2,1100
3,2000
4,1900

Comment: It works for me, see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MfIgDppDLmMRD3RjMKT8?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks Gerado and Mark. I have added a screenshot of the code's behaviour on Mozilla firefox.In the background it does have the column values in the right arrays but when hover over the fields, it shows the incorrect values.

Answer (score -1):

It may be an issue with Excel - I've had issues with CSV data from Excel.
The solution for me was just to copy the data from Excel and paste it into a text editor, then saved my CSV through that.